# Strange sum behavior in R

Tags: r

Can someone tell me whats going on here?

```
> check
[1] 1 5 4 6 7
> sum(check[1]:check[4])
[1] 21
```

Shouldn't this sum to 16?

Comment: You are doing `sum(1:6)` ie. check[1] is 1 and check[4] is 6

Answer (score 6):

You asked for sum(1:6). If you wanted the sum of the first 4 items in check it would be:

```
sum( check[1:4] )
```

The ":" function first evaluates its flanking arguments, in your case finding 1 and 6 and then returns that sequence.

Comment: to which package that `check` function belong to? Thank you.

Comment: `check` is just a vector : `check <- c(1,5,4,6,7)`

Comment: @SabDeM: There's no check function. `check' in that example was a numeric vector.

Comment: @BondedDust I was drunk for sure do did not realize that.

Comment: I suppose from a mathematical (although not from an R terminology) perspective `check[` could be considered a "function". It does return a value for numeric input. So the rule for you is "Don't drink and derive"